# Ada Numeric Literals and Underline

Tags: ada, literals

This is from the online Ada reference manual:
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/RM.pdf  (section 2.3)

> A decimal_literal is a numeric_literal in the conventional decimal
> notation (that is, the base is ten).  Syntax  decimal_literal ::=
> numeral [.numeral] [exponent]
> **numeral ::= digit {[underline] digit}**  exponent ::= E [+] numeral | E – numeral digit ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 An
> exponent for an integer literal shall not have a minus sign.  Static
> Semantics
> **An underline character in a numeric_literal does not affect its meaning.** The letter E of an exponent can be  written either in lower
> case or in upper case, with the same meaning.

If I do

```
my_literal ::= 123_456;
```

what does the underscore (underline) mean? **It says it doesn't affect the meaning**. Then what is it for? I am sure there is a simple answer but reading and re-reaidng the passage hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same reason for, say, commas (<kbd>,</kbd>) in currency or [other large] numbers: grouping.
Thus:

```ada
Million : Constant:= 1_000_000;
```

Furthermore, you could use it in conjunction with base-setting as a set-up for masking:

```ada
Type Bit is Range 1..8;
SubType Byte is Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
Type Masks is Array(Positive Range <>) of Byte;

Mask_Map : Constant Masks(Bit):=
    (
        2#0000_0001#,
        2#0000_0010#,
        2#0000_0100#,
        2#0000_1000#,
        2#0001_0000#,
        2#0010_0000#,
        2#0100_0000#,
        2#1000_0000#
    );
```

Then perhaps you would use Mask_Map and bits together with `or`, `and`, and `xor` to do bit-manipulation. The above method may seem a bit more work than the simple definition of a lot of constants and directly manipulating them, but it is more flexible in that you can later change it into a function and not have to change any client-code, that could further be useful if that function's result was a parametrized integer, where bit has the definition `1..PARAMETER'Size`.

Comment: Yes. Ada had maintainability as a design goal.

Comment: You *do* have to be aware that two consecutive underlines is an error. [IIRC]

Comment: Right. That also goes for variable names, right? My_Var is ok, My__Var is an error.

Comment: Certainly for the identifier-names, and probable for the literal.I'm not %100 sure on that, I seem to recall it being so.

Comment: @Shark8: As are leading or trailing underscores.

Comment: @Shark8: According to the quote from RM given in the question, this is also true for literals.